# Python advice: Compile list of urls that contain keyword but only include unique valid links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm still learning my way around Python so I'm hoping someone can help me think this problem through and avoid some manual steps.

I need to compile/create a list of the form

```
Institution, LinkToSpecificWebPage
```

where the Link comprises a specific work (for this argument lets say "store")

The issue I face is that each Institution can use a different form or structure to the web address of the WebPage I need (some use store.institution.tld, others institution.tld/store
Also depending on the web platform the Institution uses it may be the full url or it could be a relative link like /store

I've used BS4 to return all the links that contain "store" and printed them out.

My question is how do I build a list so that each institution is listed and for each institution there is a full url to their store

Is there a more elegant way than if statements and tests for http or www strings?

**Sample of links found**
The code outputs the Institutional Name, Institution HomePage (both from an earlier process and then from each HomePage the link(s) containing the text I'm interested in. 
I've removed some of the duplicates but as you can image sometimes the same link appears multiple times on a page so its possible there is a well formed complete link returned but its not necessarily the 1st

```
InstName,HomePage.url,link.get('href')

Marino Institute http://www.mie.ie/ /Library.aspx
TCD http://www.tcd.ie/ /Library/
DIT http://www.dit.ie/ http://dit.ie/library/
IT Tallaght http://www.it-tallaght.ie/ libraryservice3
LYIT http://www.lyit.ie/#!prettyPhoto http://library1.lyit.ie/
DCU http://www.dcu.ie/ /library/index.shtml
NUIG http://www.nuigalway.ie/ //www.library.nuigalway.ie/
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of the page you are scraping, showing some of these institutions and their links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python urlparse (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)) you could parse each partial url and then reassemble the parts back into one url. I made the following with the assumption that if there is a domain in the 3rd column then that url takes precedence over what is found in the 2nd column.

```
from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

data = [["Marino Institute","http://www.mie.ie/","/Library.aspx"],
["TCD", "http://www.tcd.ie/", "/Library/"],
["DIT", "http://www.dit.ie/", "http://dit.ie/library/"],
["IT Tallaght", "http://www.it-tallaght.ie/", "libraryservice3"],
["LYIT", "http://www.lyit.ie/#!prettyPhoto", "http://library1.lyit.ie/"],
["DCU", "http://www.dcu.ie/", "/library/index.shtml"],
["NUIG", "http://www.nuigalway.ie/", "//www.library.nuigalway.ie/"]]


def merge_urls(partial_url1, partial_url2):

    o1 = urlsplit(partial_url1)
    o2 = urlsplit(partial_url2)

    # domain of o2 takes precedence over domain in o1
    if(o2.netloc != ''):
        o3 = o2
        o2 = o1
        o1 = o3

    schemes, netlocs, paths, queries, fragments = zip(o1, o2)
    scheme = schemes[0] if schemes[0] != '' else schemes[1]
    netloc = netlocs[0] if netlocs[0] != '' else netlocs[1]
    path = paths[0] if paths[0] != '/' else paths[1]
    query = queries[0] if queries[0] != '' else queries[1]
    fragment = fragments[0] if fragments[0] != '' else fragments[1]

    return urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))

for d in data:
    print d[0], merge_urls(d[1], d[2])
```

This outputs,

```
Marino Institute http://www.mie.ie/Library.aspx
TCD http://www.tcd.ie/Library/
DIT http://dit.ie/library/
IT Tallaght http://www.it-tallaght.ie/libraryservice3
LYIT http://library1.lyit.ie/#!prettyPhoto
DCU http://www.dcu.ie/library/index.shtml
NUIG http://www.library.nuigalway.ie/
```